# Distinct() to return List<> returning Duplicates

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a list of Filters that are passed into a webservice and I iterate over the collection and do Linq query and then add to the list of products but when I do a `GroupBy` and `Distinct()` it doesn't remove the duplicates. I am using a `IEnumerable` because when you use `Disinct` it converts it to `IEnumerable`. If you know how to construct this better and make my function return a type of `List<Product>` that would be appreciated thanks.

Here is my code in C#:

```
if (Tab == "All-Items")
{
    List<Product> temp = new List<Product>();
    List<Product> Products2 = new List<Product>();
    foreach (Filter filter in Filters)
    {                        
        List<Product> products = (from p in db.Products where p.Discontinued == false
                                  && p.DepartmentId == qDepartment.Id
                                  join f in db.Filters on p.Id equals f.ProductId
                                  join x in db.ProductImages on p.Id equals x.ProductId
                                  where x.Dimension == "180X180"
                                  && f.Name == filter.Name /*Filter*/
                                  select new Product
                                  {
                                      Id = p.Id,
                                      Title = p.Title,
                                      ShortDescription = p.ShortDescription,
                                      Brand = p.Brand,
                                      Model = p.Model,
                                      Image = x.Path,
                                      FriendlyUrl = p.FriendlyUrl,
                                      SellPrice = p.SellPrice,
                                      DiscountPercentage = p.DiscountPercentage,
                                      Votes = p.Votes,
                                      TotalRating = p.TotalRating
                                  }).ToList<Product>();

        foreach (Product p in products)
        {
            temp.Add(p);
        }                        

        IEnumerable temp2 = temp.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Distinct();
        IEnumerator e = temp.GetEnumerator();
        while (e.MoveNext()) {
            Product c = e.Current as Product;
            Products2.Add(c);
        }
    }
    pf.Products = Products2;// return type must be List<Product>                
}
```

Comment: I see you are using ToList earlier in your code - you can use it on your return value too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning the `GroupBy` result to `temp2`, but then you never use it!

```
IEnumerable temp2 = temp.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Distinct();         
IEnumerator e = temp.GetEnumerator();   // <- why temp and not temp2???
```

But you aren't really using the `GroupBy` operator properly at all. You need to group and then select an item from each group, not select the distinct groups. The groups are *already distinct*.

When you group by the Id, you'll actually return a structure like this

```
-Key: 1
   -Product (Id = 1)
-Key: 2
   -Product (Id = 2)
   -Product (Id = 2)
```

You need to retrieve an item from each group. Assuming the *are* duplicates, you won't care which item you get so you can just take the first item from each group.

```
var groups = temp.GroupBy(x => x.Id);
var distinctItems = groups.Select(g => g.First());

foreach (var item in distinctItems)
{
    // do stuff with item
    Products2.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: ...why are you still calling Distinct?

Comment: @sq33G good pickup ;) purely because I cut & pasted the original code and forgot to remove it. Fixed now.

Comment: I tried you're example and it didn't work and this part here Product c = e.Current as Product; doesn't exist in the context any other suggestions

Comment: My mistake it works thanks heaps I learned something new today cheers by the way my name is Kirk aswell!

Answer (score 4):

You need to override `Equals` **and `GetHashCode`** to compare `Product`s by value.

Comment: I've never done overrides HasCodes could you do it for or give an example what to do.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode

Comment: Yeah I don't really understand all of it Im doing this in a webservice class I don't know really where to start.

Comment: Do i override Equals and GetHashCode in my class Product

Comment: Yes.  Alternatively, you can create an `IEqualityComparer<Product>` and pass it to `Distinct()`.

Comment: Or use `GroupBy`, like he's attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

SLaks is right, you have to override the Equals() and GetHashCode() methods to accomplish this.

Here is how I did it within an Order object in small program I wrote. Hope this helps!

```
    //overridden Equals() method from the Object class, determines equality based on order number
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        bool equal;
        if (this.GetType() != obj.GetType())
            equal = false;
        else
        {
            Order temp = (Order)obj;
            if(OrderNumber == temp.OrderNumber)
                equal = true;
            else
                equal = false;
        }
        return equal;
    }

    //overridden GetHashCode() method from Object class, sets the unquie identifier to OrderNumber
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return OrderNumber;
    }
```

Comment: when you say object class is that for my class Product or my webservice im confused where to put it

Comment: and what do i need to change in my code that I provided can you update what I put up

Comment: You want to do it in your Product class since that is what you are trying to compare.

Comment: Just add something similar to the code I posted within your Product class. I'm assuming ID is your unique identifier for your products so just replace OrderNumber with ID and it should work.

Comment: and the code I provided that does the Distinct and Enumerator part is that code ok or does that need to change